# virtualbox port forwarding - firewall config

Tags: linux, iptables, virtualbox, port-forwarding, shorewall

i have a ubuntu host system with virtualbox running a windows server. In Virtualbox i have configured the network with a NAT interface and port forwarding for the RDP deamon running inside the vm.

That works really well - i can connect to the windows rdp service over the internet.
TCP *:3389 -> *:3389

Now i like to restrict the access to the rdp service to only 3 public ip addresses and have no idea how to do that via iptables / shorewall.

Something like:

ACCEPT net:91.x.x.x fw tcp 3389

(shorewall rule) isn't working.

Would be glad for any hint.

Comment: You're using VirtualBox to host a production Windows VM?

Comment: That's the plan. It's just a desktop for 3 employees running a business software in terminal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ...
I had a typo in my IP address.

Everything works like a charm now I fixed that.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.